# Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine

Tags: java, ant, jboss

I am tried to run ant Project but getting below error

> Unrecognized option: -classic Error: Could not create the Java Virtual
>   Machine. Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
>   Press any key to continue . . .

run.bat contain below setting

```
set JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -Xms3072m -Xmx3072m -Djava.util.logging.config.file=%JBOSS_HOME%\server\all\conf\logging.properties

set JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -XX:+CMSPermGenSweepingEnabled -XX:MaxPermSize=2048M


set JAVA_OPTS=-classic -Xdebug -Djava.compiler=NONE -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=8787,server=y,suspend=n %JAVA_OPTS%
```

System configuration:

- OS - Window 7
- Ram - 8gb

Comment: Remove `-classic` from `set JAVA_OPTS=-classic `

Comment: Thank You ..  Working Fine...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The -classic option in your JAVA_OPTS variable was removed in Java 1.4. The option was used in Java 1.3 to invoke the Java 1.2 classic VM.

So if you're using a recent version of Java, you need to remove the option from your JAVA_OPTS variable.

Comment: i use  java 8 .. any new option

Comment: @ValaManoj Why do you think it's necessary?

Comment: @ValaManoj there's no other option because the Java 1.2 classic VM is no longer shipped with the new JDKs.

Comment: @luc14n0 I remove -classic option now working Fine.. Thank You